# Move to home screen on process cancel : Android App

Tags: android, android-fragments

[This is Signup Screen. Part of EverYou Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7KzC.png)

Problem: Click on skip move to TOP Tab.

[All Tab With Fragment Attached, Tap tab is marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGE1A.png)

I am beginner in android and implement some chunk of code for this problem but not working..

1st Attempt of my code :

```
        FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment mFrag = new TopFragment();
        t.replace(R.layout.signup_fragment, mFrag);
        t.commit();
```

"Error is : wrong 2nd argument type in 3rd line."

2nd Attempt of code:

```
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();
        ExcerptsFragment f = (ExcerptsFragment) ContainerActivity.      .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag("#tab"));
        f.triggerRefresh();
```

"Error is: Exception is main "NullPointException""

Where as Top tab set working fine with following code

Main.java

```
@Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position == fragments.size() - 1)
                    tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else {
                    if (tabLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tabs.setSelected(position);
                }
            }


        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            int tab = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("#tab", 0);
            pager.setCurrentItem(tab);
            tabs.setSelected(tab);
        }
```

Comment: on which line you got error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();

MenuPageActivity instantFragment = new MenuPageActivity();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_fragment, instantFragment);
      transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

I don't kw what kind of fragment you use, but you can try like that.
I put my code please make it for your project if you can.